# Pulling Byte from SQL Python returning bytearray

Tags: python, sql, pdf

I am attempting to retrieve a PDF attachment from a table in MS SQL Server 2008.  It is being stored as byte type, but is being returned in my query as a bytearray type.  When I try to write that to the pdf file, I'm receiving a "file corrupt" message.  Below is my code.  I am attempting to copy this pdf file from the SQL server to a local folder.

import pyodbc, os, base64, array

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=SQL')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT content FROM digitalassetcontent")
results = cursor.fetchone()
for row in results:
    # print()
    with open("Output1.txt", "wb") as output_file:
        output_file.write(row)
```

Expected output of the query =

```
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
```

Sample Output I am receiving when running query =

```
bytearray(b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xff\xe2\x0cXICC_PROFILE\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x0cHLino\x02\x10\x00\x00mntrRGB XYZ \x07\xce\x00\x02\x00\t\x00\x06\x001\x00\x00acspMSFT\x00\x00\x00\x00IEC sRGB\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf6\xd6\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd3-HP  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11cprt\x00\x00\x01P\x00\x00\x003desc\x00\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00\x00lwtpt\x00\x00\x01\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x14bkpt\x00\x00\x02\x04\x00\x00\x00\x14rXYZ\x00\x00\x02\x18\x00\x00\x00\x14gXYZ\x00\x00\x02,\x00\x00\x00\x14bXYZ\x00\x00\x02@\x00\x00\x00\x14dmnd\x00\x00\x02T\x00\x00\x00pdmdd\x00\x00\x02\xc4\x00\x00\x00\x88vued\x00\x00\x03L\x00\x00\x00\x86view\x00\x00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone curious in the future, I ended up using SQL Server Business Intelligence Development.    Using a Control Flow from OLE DB Source --> Export Column

```
declare @path varchar(100)= 'C:\images\'

SELECT content
,@path+b.att_name AS Path
FROM dbo.digitalassetcontent as a join dbo.attachment as b on a.content_key = b.content_key
```